Why does CUDA show similar performance between write through (adding volatile keyword) and write back under light load when testing write performance
I think under light load, because write back requires writing data to the cache first and waiting for it to be flushed to the global memory, this mode should cause performance waste because there will be a certain lag when data is flushed out. On the contrary, write through allows data to be directly updated to global memory, which should result in better performance.
Here is my understanding:

My test results on 1050ti and A100 are the same.(Using the nsight system to calculate time consumption)
The following is the test kernel, the code is simple, just a simple test for writing bandwidth.(Light load)
    __global__ voild cuda_peek(volatile uint *a)
    {
        uint gidx=(blockIdx.x  * blockDim.x + thread.x );
        a[gidx] = gidx+10;
    }

    int block_num=6*32; //6 is the number of sm for 1050ti
    int loop=100;
    int block_size=1024;
    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    dim3 gridDim,blockDim;
    gridDim.x=block_num;
    gridDim.y=1;
    gridDim.z=1;
    blockDim.x=block_size;
    blockDim.y=1;
    blockDim.z=1;
    
    cuda_peek<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(A);
    cudaEventRecord(start);
    for(uint i=0;i<loop;i++)
    {
    cuda_peek<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(A);
    }
   cudaEventRecord(stop);
  
    cudaEventSynchronize...
    cudaMemcpy...


Sorry, maybe I didn't express myself clearly. What I mean is that in GPU, write back needs to first store the data in the internal cache, and there may be two situations where the data will be refreshed:

Only when a new request arrives will the old dirty data be refreshed
A flush request has arrived to refresh all data.
So in this process, the data will be written to the cache first, and then updated externally after a period of time, which theoretically may have some impact on performance.


Ah, sorry, you talk about device memory! I didn't realize because write-through is usually associated with host buffer allocations. I'll delete my old comments. Anyway, how do you measure performance waste?

In fact, I tested on A100 and 1050ti and found that there was no performance loss for write back compared to write through. However, I theoretically feel that there may be a performance gap, so I am curious about what measures Nvidia has taken to prevent performance loss. Or maybe my understanding is not quite right?

"waiting for it to be flushed to the global memory" Why would the kernel wait on that flush in the absence of a memory fence? Your question might become clearer if you would include code, ideally a full minimal, reproducible example.

Fun fact: For kernels that do not just write out, but update (e.g. +=)  locations in global memory (no race condition, every thread has its own location) one can use atomics as an optimization as they offload the + to the memory system. This also goes around caches, but to my understanding the improvement comes from avoiding the read latency, not from avoiding the write latency as alluded to in above comment.

I have updated the code, and since I read out the results at the end of the kernel, I think theoretically the kernel needs to wait for the results to be written to global memory before it ends.

I also drew a picture to illustrate my understanding, hoping that I can express it clearly.

Someone may correct me on this, but I don't think the L1 cache in Ampere (A100) is coherent. The Turing tuning guide mentions that L1 is write-through and the Ampere guide does not mention any changed with that. If the cache is write-through, your scenario does not apply, even if your benchmark was able to observe it (which I doubt).

Also the latency of writing to cache should be much smaller than when writing to DRAM, so even if the picture were qualitatively accurate, quantitatively the difference would be a small percentage of the total latency instead of the factor 2 in the picture.

What is your execution configuration (number of blocks and threads per block)? Are you benchmarking a realistic situation with multiple blocks and waves per SM allowing latency hiding, or are you trying to make the latency visible by using a single block or even a single warp? Again, an MRE would avoid all this back and forth...

Instead of just using volatile which only affects L1 caching and compiler optimization, I recommend using the store functions using cache hints. Reading the PTX documentation section linked from there and comparing the PTX/SASS produced by these hints, no hints and volatile might also bring better understanding.

I updated my test code on 1050ti and also tried __stwb and __stwt, but the results still haven't changed. (I checked the code of ptx and found that the corresponding st has changed to st.global-wb \ st.global-wt)  :(

What I want to express in the picture is that the performance of the write in cache part is mainly affected by the cache bandwidth rather than latency. In addition, the data size of my test case is 0.75MB (the L2 cache size of 1050ti is 1MB)

Wait, you are talking about the L2 cache? The L2 is a coherent cache and it is not flushed at the end of a kernel except by the profiler if you enable the appropriate option. And that option exists only to make benchmarking predictable. Further, the __stcs and __stwt functions are appropriate if the store potentially exceeds the cache size and you don't want the stores to evict other cache lines that have a better chance of being reused. None of these options will improve the performance of a kernel that only writes. It can only improve reading of other data

The only time you can potentially see the effect that you are talking about is if the L1 is write-back but non-coherent. Then the default st.wb store policy means that, as the PTX documentation reads, the driver must invalidate global L1 cache lines between dependent grids of thread arrays. But since your L1 caches are, as far as I can tell, write-through, that does not happen.

Ah, I used to think that coherence was related to the type of request.  I looked through some Spec and didn't seem to find any information about L2 being a coherent cache. Could you tell me where I can find the relevant explanation?

Coherence is the default so docs usually only mentions non-coherence, e.g. concerning the texture cache (that is unified with the L1 cache). L2 cache coherence is mentioned in the PTX ld.ca description: Global data is coherent at the L2 level, but multiple L1 caches are not coherent for global data. Also, the docs are more about effects than implementation details. So you will usually find descriptions such as reserving __ldg for the "read-only data cache", meaning the non-coherent L1/texture cache.

ok thanks! That seems to be quite different between IMG's GPU and NVIDIA's. As far as I know, Imagination's GPU usually controls whether it is coherent or not based on the request type (write back is non coherent, write through is coherent).

If the default is coherent, then it can be understood that there is no difference in performance between wband wt, because wb will also update memory data while updating cache data. From the perspective of the entire pipeline, the behavior of wb and wt is similar(the pipeline I drew in my diagram is incorrect)


Why does CUDA show similar performance etc. ?

If for no other reason - because you're micro-benchmarking wrong.
Your code will yield no meaningful result because the overheads are very high relative to the work; and just the performance "noise" might be of a higher order of magnitude than what you're testing. To test behavior of some sequence of instructions:

Perform them in many threads per block (unless it's a block-level phenomenon).
Perform them in many many blocks (several times lot more than the GPU can have "in-flight" at a given time).
Run the sequence many times in a loop, in each thread (so that the thread setup overhead is small/negligible)

The fact that you schedule the kernel many times may help the "perf noise" somewhat - but relative to a mean which is meaningless (pun not intended).
